# how to read input string until a blank line in C?

Tags: c

first of all i'm new to coding in C.

I tried to read a string of unknowns size from the user until a blank line is given and then save it to a file, and after that to read the file.

I've only managed to do it until a new line is given and I don't know how to look for a blank line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *input(FILE* fp, size_t size) {
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);
    if (!str)return str;
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n') {
        str[len++] = ch;
        if (len == size) {
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size += 16));
            if (!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++] = '\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *istr;
    printf("input string : ");
    istr = input(stdin, 10);
    //write to file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("1.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, istr);
    fclose(fp);

    //read file
    char c;
    fp = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
         printf("%c", c);
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);

    free(istr);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `EOF` cannot be stored in `char`, so the type of `c` to store what is returned from `fgetc()` should be `int`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Are you serious? isn't `EOF` on most systems (-1) ? A signed  `char` can store a value between -128 and 127

Comment: @layzak Yes. Characters returned from `fgetc()` is range of `unsigned char`. Converting `EOF` to fit in `char` isn't a good idea because it will make it unable to distinguish one of possible character and `EOF`.

Comment: If `realloc` fails, you leak memory.

Comment: What do you consider the difference between a "*new line*" and a "*blank line*"?

Comment: @layzak "A signed char can store a value between -128 and 127" --> that is 256 different values.  `fgetc()` typically  returns 257 different values (values in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`).  Not possible to distinctively store those results in a `char`, hence the use of `int`.  So `EOF`, when it has a value like -1, can be stored in a `char`, but then some other character read can have the same value when saved as a signed `char`.  Further, on systems where `char` is  unsigned, `char ch;     while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp))` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a flag or a counter. For a counter you could simply increase the counter each character found. If a new line is found and the counter is 0 it must be a blank line. If a new line character is found and the counter is not 0, it must be the end of the line so reset the counter to 0 and continue.

Something like this:

```
int count = 0;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        count = 0;
        str[len++] = ch;
    }
    else
    {
        str[len++] = ch;
        ch++;
    }
}
```

Another way would be to simply check if the last character in the string was a new line.

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if(ch == '\n' && str[len - 1] == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But please add `len` variable into your example.

Answer (score 2):

I would restructure your code a little.  I would change your `input()` function to be a function (`readline()`?) that reads a single line.  In `main()` I would loop reading line by line via `readline()`.

If the line is empty (only has a newline -- use `strcmp(istr, "\n")`), then free the pointer, and exit the loop.  Otherwise write the line to the file and free the pointer.

If your concept of an empty line includes `"     \n"` (prefixed spaces), then write a function `is_only_spaces()` that returns a true value for a string that looks like that.

While you could handle the empty line in `input()`, there is value in abstracting the line reading from the input termination conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A blank line is a line which contains only a newline, right ? So you can simply keep the last 2 characters you read. If they are `'\n'`, then you have detected a blank line : the first `'\n'` is the end of the previous line, the second one is the end of the current line (which is a blank line).

```
char *input(FILE* fp, size_t size) {
    char *str;
    int ch, prev_ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);
    if (!str)return str;
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp)) && (ch != '\n' && prev_ch != '\n')) {
        str[len++] = ch;
        if (len == size) {
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size += 16));
            if (!str)return str;
        }
        prev_ch = ch;
    }
    str[len++] = '\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}
```

Note that parenthesis around `ch != '\n' && prev_ch != '\n'` are here to make the condition more understandable.

To improve this, you can keep your function that reads only a line and test if the line returned is empty (it contains only a `'\n'`).

Comment: that's not possible, if `ch` is `\n` then also `prev_ch` will be `\n` and then im in the same problem.

Comment: Yes but when `prev_ch` will be `'\n'`, `ch` will be the next character.